# Finding positive semi-definite counterexamples for self-adjoint bounded operators on a Hilbert Space.

Tags: matrices, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, positive-semidefinite, self-adjoint-operators

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space. Assume $x, y \in B(\mathcal{H})$ are self-adjoint. We say $x \geq y$ if $x-y$ is positive semi-definite. We define positive semi-definite as $\langle x \xi, \xi \rangle \geq 0$ for all $\xi \in \mathcal{H}$.

I am looking for specific examples to illustrate the following statements:

**(1) $x,y \geq 0 \nRightarrow xy \geq 0.$**

I looked for an example of two matrices such that both are positive semi-definite but their product is not, but I couldn't find an example where the matrices are symmetric (since I want $x,y$ self-adjoint). I only saw examples online where the matrices were not symmetric.

**(2)  $x \geq y \geq 0 \nRightarrow x^2 \geq y^2.$**

By the definition above, we are looking for $x$ and $y$ self-adjoint such that $(x-y)$ and $y$ are both positive semi-definite, but $(x^2-y^2)$ is not. Again I looked for matrices that would satisfy this but had no luck.

Are matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ a bad example of $B(\mathcal{H})$ to take for these situations?

Comment: I realize after the fact that this question had a solution:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141094/in-a-c-algebra-does-a-leq-b-imply-a2-leq-b2?rq=1

Posting for visibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2x2 matrices are enough to see these things.

For the first one: consider
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} \text{ and } B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$
Both are positive, but
$$AB = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, $$
which is not self-adjoint, hence not positive.

For the second one, lets use the same matrices! Clearly $A \geq B \geq 0$ (as $A - B$ is a positive multiple of a projection), but
$$ A^2 - B^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 3 \\ 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix}, $$
which has eigenvalue $3 - \sqrt{10} < 0$, so it cannot be positive.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Quick question, the AB you gave in the first part is not symmetric but it does have only non-negative eigenvalues right? So isn't it positive semi-definite still, or MUST we have symmetric?

Comment: Positive semi-definite here requires being self-adjoint (symmetric when the entries are real). An operator $T$ is positive (i.e., $\langle T\xi,\xi \rangle \geq 0 \forall \xi$) if and only if $T$ is self-adjoint and the spectrum of $T$ is is contained in $[0,\infty)$. In $M_2$, the spectrum is just the set of eigenvalues, so having non-negative eigenvalues is not enough to ensure positivity of $AB$.