# When does $a \leq b \implies a^2 \leq b^2 ?$in C* algebra

Tags: inequality, c-star-algebras

It is known that in arbitrary C*-algebra, it is not true  $a \leq b \implies a^2 \leq b^2 $

**my question:**

> when does  $a \leq b \implies a^2 \leq b^2 ?$

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking which algebras the implication is universally valid in -- or, given a particular algebra, which $a$ and $b$ is it true for?

Comment: I mean which algebras the implication

Comment: If the algebra has any nonzero element $x$, then
$$ -x^*x \le 0 \quad\text{yet}\quad (-x^*x)^2 \not\le 0^2 $$
So a nontrivial algebra _never_ satisfies your implication for all $a, b$.

Comment: When $0\leq a\leq b$ and $a$ and $b$ commute, we have $a^2\leq b^2$.  Other than that, I doubt you'll find a satisfying answer

Comment: Aweygan, would you give me a reference or proof please

Comment: @user62498 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3808830/finding-positive-semi-definite-counterexamples-for-self-adjoint-bounded-operator/3808909#3808909

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141094/in-a-c-algebra-does-a-leq-b-imply-a2-leq-b2?rq=1

Here are concrete counter-examples, with the latter containing a reference about the commutative case.

Comment: PStheman,Thank you so much